# Action Script 3.0 from 2.0 Falling Randomly Placed Objects and a countdown timer

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

Looking for some help on a lesson I teach to my pupils in Flash Animation.
Not overly familiar with the code, I can essentially do this one thing

I have four layers on my animation. Background, snow, timer and action script.

I have the following code on my snow layer (which has a simple oval in white on it)

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    movieWidth=550;
    movieHeight=400;

    i=1+Math.random()*2;
    k = -Math.PI+Math.random()*Math.PI;

    this._xscale = this._yscale=50+Math.random()*100;
    this._alpha = 60+Math.random()*100;
    this._x = -10+Math.random()*movieWidth;
    this._y = -10+Math.random()*movieHeight;

}

onClipEvent (enterFrame){

    rad += (k/180)*Math.PI;
    this._x -= Math.cos(rad);
    this._y += i;
    if(this._y>=movieHeight){
        this._y = -5;
    }
    if((this._x>=movieWidth) || (this._x<=0)){
        this._x = -10+Math.random()*movieWidth;
        this._y = -5;
    }
}
```

and this on my action script layer

```
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    var today:Date = new Date();
    var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    var currentTime = today.getTime();
    var targetDate:Date = new Date(currentYear, 11, 25);
    var targetTime = targetDate.getTime();
    var timeLeft = targetTime - currentTime();
    var sec = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);
    var min = Math.floor(sec/60);
    var hours = Math.floor(min/60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours/24);

    sec = String(sec % 60);
    if(sec.length < 2){
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    min = String(min % 60);
    if(min.length < 2){
        min = "0" + min;
    }

    hours = String(hours % 24);
    if(hours.length < 2){
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    days = String(days)
    var counter:String = days + " Days\n" + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    time_txt.text = counter;

}

for (k=0; k<100; k++){
    duplicateMovieClip(this.snow, "snow"+k, k);
}
```

I know this worked previously in AS2, but I have trouble getting it to work.

Currently getting a syntax error which wasn't there when I used an older version

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine except this line : `var timeLeft = targetTime - currentTime();` which should be : `var timeLeft = targetTime - currentTime;`, weher `currentTime` is a var and not a function ...

Comment: If you're using this to teach, it might be better in just repackaging it all in AS3 - getting rid of the timeline code and showing them how to set things up where they will find more examples to explore on their own.

Comment: Gone3D - it's a 'last week of term' activity for pupils who are given the code. It's just something fun for them to see what is achievable in Flash.
Unfortunately, my expertise is limited to Motion Tween and Shape Tween and a few little bits and pieces to make simple animation.
The pupils loved doing this previously having the countdown timer for Christmas (although, I'll be using Star Wars for my example)

The pupils who are doing it are 11/12 years old and have had limited experience of 'typed' code too

Comment: @OLi Did you see my 1st comment ?! Your ActionScript 2 code is fine except the line : `var timeLeft = targetTime - currentTime();` ... also I don't know why you'v mentioned the ActionScript 3 in your question ?!

Comment: @akmozo thanks for your patience. I made this with an older version of Flash when it supported AS2, the new version I have, it doesn't work at all. It doesn't support any AS3.

Comment: @OLi You should know that AS3 (ActionScript 3) and AS2 (ActionScript 2) are different. Your code is an ActionScript 2 code and I think the only Flash that do not support AS2 is Flash CC ... So which version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using flash player 6 syntax with flash player 5 elements (`onClipEvent()` handlers assignable to movieclips on the timeline). I don't think one could possibly expect to see something like that now... As it started getting outdated by late 2001, when FP 6 with (almost) fully ECMA262-compliant ActionScript 1.0 emerged.

Anyway, you can compile it after setting `File -> Publish Settings... -> Script` option to ActionScript 1.0 or ActionScript 2.0. Your code does work this way, I copied and pasted it to make sure. Be carefull to place the `onClipEvent()` code **on the snow clip** and not on the timeline frame. This is the FP5 way of handling events. And the rest of the code goes to timeline frame (I guess this is what you did).

You may also need to change target Flash Player version in case your IDE doesn't allow you to set script version to 1.0 without that (with Flash Pro CS6 this is not the case).

[image]

Working example (open in CS5 or newer): [snowCS5.fla](http://noregret.org/temp/snowCS5.fla)

Comment: I've looked under the pathway you suggested, I can't change the output from 3.0 to 2.0. Any other suggestions?
Thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: @OLi I've updated the answer, hope that helps... Because your code, ancient as it is, **does work**. :) Provide the error text if it doesn't compile.

Comment: no errors, as my version just doesn't let me select any other script than AS1
Although, I do get an error saying there is a missing bracket expected in Line 1 ...

Comment: @OLi Sorry, but you previously said that you could not change version **from** 3.0, now you are saying that 1.0 is the only option available to you. A added a working fla file to my answer, don't know what else I can do here.

Comment: I appreciate you doing that and apologies for the mistake. I'm running about crazy at school with other things!

I meant I can only have the settings on AS3!!! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I just get the same issues with that. It says AS1 cannot be supported ... You wouldn't know how to complete the same in AS3? I can get the timer working no problem. It's the random falling objects which I cannot achieve!

Thanks

Comment: @OLi Ok, does this work in your browser: http://noregret.org/temp/snowCS5.html ? This is your code without any changes. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Perfectly!

We are using CC 2015 - which is newer than what I made it in before. I think I had 5.5 which is why I could get it working with AS2, as it had the ability to create and AS2 file!